# How to make a table with many columns in a report

Tags: birt

I would like to create a report containing a table that will not fit to one page, since it has too many columns. I want BIRT to create a report that you can print and put the pages next to each other to get the whole table.

An Example:
My table has 20 columns, 10 fit on one page. The Table has enough rows to fill 2 pages. When I put the printed pages on a table like this:

P1  -  P2

P3  -  P4

I see the whole table with all 20 columns. How can I do that with BIRT report designer 3.7.0?

Comment: Just wanted to open the same question. I think it is general issue, not all the time you have a report to fit one page width. There should be a solution... so far I did not find it... when I export to pdf half of columns are cut, that's not good. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Birt is page oriented, I guess this will not work.

I guess you'll have to create one report with the whole table to display on the screen, and another "print optimized" one with two tables distributed over two pages.

Comment: In my case report is customizable, I can't create "print optimized" report in advance, it won't work this way. Even being page oriented I don't see any problem to print other columns on the next page, it still is a page...

Answer (score 0):

I actually saw a similar question on the [official BIRT eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1057776/#msg_1057776). They suggested adding a page break inside the table and that should break up the columns across the different pages (unless I mis-understood what you are trying to accomplish).